# What are $\Sigma _n^i$, $\Pi _n^i$ and $\Delta _n^i$?

Tags: reference-request, logic, notation, computability, descriptive-set-theory

Sometimes reading on wikipedia or in this site (and in very different context like topology, arithmetic and logic) I have found these symbols $\Sigma _n^i$,  $\Pi _n^i$ and $\Delta _n^i$. They are probably classes of something, but i don't know their name and i wasn't able to find something i can understand (I read about hierachies, but hierachies of what and, in which field of mathematics?)

I hope someone can give me an easy explaination of these things (classes?), how they are related, in which field(s) of mathematics these concepts appear and a formal definition (or a link).

Thanks in advance. and I apologize for errors (I'm using a translator).

**Update**

What is the meaning of the upper index $0$? In the logic use of this notation $\Sigma_n^1$ is the hieracy of the formulas in the language of second-order arithmetic. Intuitively I could think that the hierchies  $\Sigma _n^i$,  $\Pi _n^i$ and $\Delta _n^i$ are the hierachies of the formulas in the language of $(i−1)$-order arithmetic..probably I'm wrong but how this index is linked with other fields?

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking of the [projective hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_hierarchy)?

Comment: $i+1$-order formulas, not $i-1$. $\Sigma^0_n$ is first-order, and $\Sigma^1_n$ is second-order. And so on.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks, i meant that even if I typed it wrong.@AsafKaragila

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A similar notation appears in

- (In logic) [Arithmetical hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy) or [Analytical hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytical_hierarchy)
- (In descriptive set theory) [Borel hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_hierarchy) or [Projective hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_hierarchy)
- (In computer science) [Polynomial hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_hierarchy)

So it depends on context. Often (but not always) these symbols indicate that the hierarchy of object has the following diagram:

[image: Hierarchial diagram]

The meaning of the arrows depends on the context. For example, in the Borel hierarchy, $\bf\Sigma$ are families of sets closed under $\sigma$-union, $\bf \Pi$ are families closed under $\sigma$-intersection, $\bf\Delta$ are closed under both, and the arrows in the diagram indicate inclusion.

Comment: Thanks, that makes all more clear to me. At least brings order in my mind. 
Anyways, I still don't understand what is the meaning of the upper index $0$, in the logic use of this notation $\Sigma^1_n$ is the hieracy of the formulas in the language of 2nd order arithmetic.Intuitively I could think that the hierchies $\Sigma _n^i$,  $\Pi _n^i$ and $\Delta _n^i$ are the hierachies of the formulas in the language of $(i-1)$-order arithmetic..probably I'm wrong but how this index is linked with other fields?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but this book looks promising: *Kechris, A. S., Classical Descriptive Set Theory*

Comment: Thanks. Well I'll search an online version of this book, meanwhile i'll update my question.