# The symbols $\Pi^m_n$ and $\Sigma^m_n$, are used ONLY to refer to the hierarchy of formulas of PA?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

It is a very basic question, but could not find it elsewhere and I think is the source of many of the misunderstandings that I have.
My understanding is that in principle you can define a hierarchy of formulas of the form $\Pi^m_n$ and $\Sigma^m_n$, 
for any math theory, provided you use the appropriate language. 
But I am not sure if when I see those symbols in the literature they always refer to formulas of PA.

Comment: Might be related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/347297/what-are-sigma-ni-pi-ni-and-delta-ni

Comment: This is **definitely not** a question for [tag:first-order-logic]! Especially when allowing $m>0$. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the symbols are also used elsewhere. For example indescribable cardinals do not refer to cardinals which cannot be described by formulas in the language of arithmetics.

Taken from Kanamori, *The Higher Infinite*:

> $\kappa$ is *$Q$-indescribable* iff for any $R\subseteq V_\kappa$ and $Q$ sentence $\varphi$ such that $\langle V_\kappa,\in, R\rangle\models\varphi$ there is $\alpha<\kappa$ such that $\langle V_\alpha,\in,R\cap V_\alpha\rangle\models\varphi$. (p. 58)

In this context $Q$ is $\Sigma^m_n$ or $\Pi^m_n$. But the language itself is an arbitrary language containing two symbols, and certainly not over $\Bbb N$.

You can read more in the first section, (p. 5) where Kanamori discusses hierarchies of formulas.

Comment: One more: is (or can be modified to be) the definition of Q-indescribable that you gave above of the format $Pi_n^m$ or $\Sigma_n^m$, is it in some metalanguage, or does ZFC allow formulas that cannot be expressed in that format?

Comment: julian, $Q$ is a language which is in the universe, and since we talk about set model for that language we can define its truth, and encode everything within the universe. So no need to go meta here.

Comment: I do not mean Q but the whole definition given in gray, is that a formula in the language of set theory?

Comment: Yes, because we can encode high-order formula of set-structures in the universe; and we can say when they are true or false in particular set-structures.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I 've got the book and I am gonna read it. in the mean time, could you tell me in advance if the definition in gray is of the format $\Sigma_n^m$ or $\Pi_n^m$  for some m, n? or it goes beyond predicate calculus+$\in$+axioms?

Comment: julian, I don't understand this question.

Comment: ok, I'll read the book first! (I might be more confused that I thought!).